# conditional add statement in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlalchemy

Suppose I want to upload several SQL records, to a table that may not be populated yet. If there is a record with a primary key("ID") that already exists, either in the table or in the records to be committed to a table,  I want to replace the existing record with the new record. 
I'm using mssql, SQL server 2008.

My first guess would be

```
try:
    session.add(record)
    session.commit
except:
    session.query().\
        filter(Class.ID == record.ID).\
        update(some expression)
    session.commit()
```

what should the expression be? and is there a cleaner(and safer!) way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general unless using statements that guarantee atomicity, you'll always have to account for race conditions that might arise from multiple actors trying to either insert or update (don't forget delete). Even the [MERGE statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), though a single statement, can [have race conditions](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) if not used correctly.

Traditionally this kind of "upsert" is performed using stored procedures or other SQL or implementation specific features available, like the MERGE statement.

An SQLAlchemy solution has to either attempt the insert and perform an update if an integrity error is raised, or perform the udpate and attempt an insert if no rows were affected. It should be prepared to retry in case both operations fail (a row might get deleted or inserted in between):

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError

while True:  # Infinite loop, use a retry counter  if necessary
    try:
        # begin a save point, prevents the whole transaction failing
        # in case of an integrity error
        with session.begin_nested():
            session.add(record)
            # Flush instead of commit, we need the transaction intact
            session.flush()
            # If the flush is successful, break out of the loop as the insert
            # was performed
            break

    except IntegrityError:
        # Attempt the update. If the session has to reflect the changes
        # performed by the update, change the `synchronize_session` argument.
        if session.query(Class).\
                filter_by(ID=record.ID).\
                update({...},
                       syncronize_session=False):
            # 1 or more rows were affected (hopefully 1)
            break

        # Nothing was updated, perhaps a DELETE in between

    # Both operations have failed, retry

session.commit()
```

Regarding

> If there is a record with a primary key("ID") that already exists, either in the table or in the records to be committed to a table, I want to replace the existing record with the new record.

If you can be sure that no concurrent updates to the table in question will happen, you can use [`Session.merge`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) for this kind of task:

```
# Records have primary key set, on which merge can either load existing
# state and merge, or create a new record in session if none was found.
for record in records:
    merged_record = session.merge(record)
    # Note that merged_record is not record

session.commit()
```

The SQLAlchemy merge will first check if an instance with given primary key exists in the identity map. If it doesn't and `load` is passed as `True` it'll check the database for the primary key. If a given instance has no primary key or an instance cannot be found, a new instance will be created.

The merge will then copy the state of the given instance onto the located/created instance. The new instance is returned.

Comment: Why do you try the insert first, rather than the update? 
It seems to me that updating first won't raise an error, and an Integrity error might be raised in the first try block for other reasons so that is less safe.

Comment: That'd depend on your use case: will you mostly be inserting new data, or updating existing. Depending on the answer just swap the operations. You gave very little in way of an example, so all I can assume is that you'd get an integrity error from duplicate primary key, which I suppose `Class.ID` is. The block is safe as it uses a save point, which is rolled back if the insert fails. The error is caught and handled properly, so that too is safe. Any other errors should cause a rollback.

Comment: In other words: you cannot in any way check whether or not a row exists and then insert (I don't mean a single `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE NOT EXISTS ()` query). That is inherently 2 operations and will have race conditions. You have to perform the insert and see if it fails or not.

Comment: You also might get away with [`Session.merge`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html#merging) with added error handling (since it checks the local identity map + optional DB check, you still have possible races), but that depends on what "some expression" actually does, how your models are set up etc.

Comment: When using the "update({})" command, is it possible to update an entire row rather than specify every parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry, I must confess that I managed to miss in your original question that you wish to replace records completely, not just perform simple updates. If you can be sure that there'll be no concurrent updates to the table, `Session.merge` is actually a good fit for your problem: given an empty identity map in session it'll load current state from DB for record with ID and update session state based on it, or create a new one if none was found. On next flush changes are written back.

Comment: Thanks! How does one call Session.merge()? Just Session.merge(record)?

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is a much better pattern for doing this.  Do a query first to see if the record already exists, and then proceed accordingly.

Using your syntax, it would be something like the following:

```
result = session.query().filter(Class.ID == record.ID).first()

#  If record does not exist in Db, then add record
if result is None:
    try:  
       session.add(record)
       session.commit()
    except:
       db.rollback()
       log.error('Rolling back transaction in query-none block')   

#  If record does exist, then update value of record in Db
else:
   try:
        session.query().\
            filter(Class.ID == record.ID).\
            update(some expression)
        session.commit() 
   except:
       db.rollback()
       log.error('Rolling back transaction')
```

It's usually a good idea to wrap your database operations in a try/except block , so you're on the right track with the try-portion of what you wrote.  Depending on what you're doing, the except block should typically show you an error message or do a db rollback.

Comment: This fails when 2 or more concurrent actors operate on records, as they may both see that no records exist with given predicates and proceed to insert.

Comment: Yes, good point.  That's why I suggested using a try/except block for the operations.  I'll update my code.  Thanks for that.